# Lightning Scheduler - time slots are not shown for service resource where resource type is Agent

Tags: lightning, lightning-scheduler

I have setup lightning scheduler and created service resources, with resource type as `Agent`.

The issue is in the "Select Service Appointment time" screen.

Time slots are showing only for service resources, where resource type is `Technician`, not for resource type `Agent`.

**How can I configure the scheduler for service resource of type `Agent`?**

Comment: Based on [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_create_resources.htm&type=5) resource type needs to be set to Technician.

Comment: Yeah right, but we have service resources in prod of type "Agent". Also existing code is referring service resource of type "Agent". So I am looking for any workaround on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late. But if any one else is looking for an answer.

According to [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_create_resources.htm&type=5) you have to *enable Main Service Resource setting is enabled and the Main checkbox is selected* to use the Agent type of Service Resource.